# What is calculated when they show the pit stops times in F1?

Tags: formula-1

In F1 they often show Pit Stop times like these

[image]

What is actually calculated? When does the timer start, and when does the timer stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The times given there are the [lengths of time the car was stationary in the pit box](https://www.formula1.com/en/latest/features/2017/1/f1-quest-perfect-pit-stop.html), apparently being measured using high speed camera footage. While obviously an impressive achievement to perform a pit stop in that timeframe, it's only a part of the longer "[pit lane time](https://jwgrandprix.com/2016/07/18/formula-one-pit-stop-time-vs-pit-lane-times/)" measure which influences race strategy, and can also be affected by the pit lane speed limit, and pit lane traffic.

Comment: So in theory it's from when the wheel come to a complete stop to when they start to move again.